# Several sites on multiple servers in 2 data-centers. How would one approach implementing unified user login?

Tags: php

Several sites on multiple servers in 2 data-centers.

How should one approach implementing shared users database, shared way for users to login into those sites so there would be no need to keep separate users database on each server?
Is creating some web-service a way to go? Like some REST endpoint over https? or some oauth authentication is the right way?

Advice wanted:)

Answer (score 3):

Creating Api either rest or SOAP is best way to implement unified user login i would have write this i comments but cant comment till reputation is 50

Comment: have you ever used this approach? So basically user submits credentials to my site, then I do http request from PHP to for example: `https://www.auth.com/endpoint?pass=pass&user=user`, if credentials are correct - return code 200 and data, otherwise 500 and no data. -> something like that?

Comment: You submit data to remote api if correct send flag like 'authorized' else 'unauthorized' in xml or json format along with other info to handle sessions stackoverflow api is best example http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: link is for 1.0 api. Version 2.1 which is their latest seem to talk about oauth authentication: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: It seems like stackoverflow's actual login is openId based?